# Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin on iOS Always Opens Web Dialog Even Though Native App is Installed

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I'm developing an Ionic/Cordova app which uses the [Cordova Facebook plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md). Up until a few days ago, using the login method opened the native app (when running on device). Then, after removing and re-adding the iOS platform, the same method started opening a webview instead of opening the native app.

The plugin [troubleshooting page](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md) offers a solution to this very issue however, I can't seem to find the place in Facebook where I can switch "Deep Linking" to ON.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the url scheme `fb<APP_ID>` wasn't set up in the Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add the following in my `plist`:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
</array>
```

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9